# Why does my antlr grammar give me an error?

Tags: antlr4

I have the little grammar below.  `node` is the start production. When my input is `(a:b)` I get an error: `line 1:1 extraneous input 'a' expecting {':', INAME}`

Why is this?

EDIT - I forgot that the lexer and parser run as a separate phases.  By the time the parser runs, the lexer has completed.  When the lexer runs it has no knowledge of the parser rules. It has already made the TYPE/INAME decision choosing TYPE per @bart's reasoning below.

```
grammar g1;

TYPE: [A-Za-z_];
INAME: [A-Za-z_];

node: '(' namesAndTypes ')';

namesAndTypes:
               INAME ':' TYPE
             | ':' TYPE
             | INAME
             ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the lexer will never produce an `INAME` token. The lexer works in the following was:

1. try to match as much characters as possible
2. when 2 or more lexer rules match the same characters, let the one defined first "win"

Because the input `"a"` and `"b"` both match the `TYPE` and `INAME` rules, the `TYPE` rule wins because it is defined first. It doesn't matter if the parser is trying to match an `INAME` rule, the lexer will not produce it. The lexer does not "listen" to he parser.

You could create some sort of `ID` rule, and then define `type` and `iname` parser rules instead:

```
ID: [A-Za-z_];

node
 : '(' namesAndTypes ')'
 ;

namesAndTypes
 : iname ':' type
 | ':' type
 | iname
 ;

type
 : ID
 ;

iname
 : ID
 ;
```